# Get class name of clicked element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some dynamically created divs . And when the user clicks on the screen I want to check if it was on one of the dynamically created divs.But it doesnt seem to work. I already have a window.addeventListener but that too is not working for the dynamically created divs.

```
            var divk = document.createElement("div");
            divk.className="divk";
             window.addEventListener('click', function(e){
                if (document.getElementById('outside_click_purpose').contains(e.target)){
                    currentItem = e.target;
                    if (currentItem.classList.contains("divk")) {
                      alert("contains !!!");
                    }
                }
           });
```

Comment: `e.originalTarget.classList.contains('outside_click_purpose')`

Comment: What you have currently is not jQuery. So you want to change over to using jQuery?

Comment: addEventlistener works , but doesn't enter the inner if loop

Comment: Yeah , any solution is okay , there is no restriction

Comment: add your html to question

Comment: you aren't ever adding the div to the dom, so how is it supposed to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use `event delegation` then use `matches`

Notice how we use

```
e.target.matches('.dynamic')
```

To check for the presence of our class, we can use any valid `css selector`

For example, if we wanted to ensure it was a div:

```
e.target.matches('div.dynamic');
```

See the demonstration below:

```js
// Add some dynamic divs
const getDiv = (content) => {
  const div = document.createElement('div');
  div.className = 'dynamic';
  div.innerHTML = content;
  return div;
};

const setMessage = (msg) => document.querySelector('.clicked').innerText = msg;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const container = document.querySelector('#container');
  for(let i = 0; i< 10; i++) {
    container.appendChild(getDiv(`Dynamic ${i}`));
  }
});

// Use event delegation
document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  if(e.target.matches('.dynamic')) {
    setMessage(`Clicked a dynamic div - text ${e.target.innerText}`);
  }
  else {
    setMessage('Click was not on dynamic');
  }
  
});
```

```css
.clicked {
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.manual {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="clicked"></div>
<div class="manual">Manual</div>
<div class="manual">Manual</div>
<div id="container"></div>
```